# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'. java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signed, build.gradle

I am new to Android Studio. I am trying to generate release signed apk file using android-studio.

While generating signed release APK it gives me error like below.
In this module I have four library files only, they are noted in dependencies list in
build.gradle file.

Please clarify which dependencies or build types are I've missed out  in this process.

I found some solutions from other users, they said please remove all library files and again add
it , then it resolves the problem. I tried in that way also but it won't works for me.

But when I tried to build release signed apk file, it gives me below warnings with  error.

I have a problem with proguard. I get this on the console page.
I added -dontworn line to proguard-project.txt

[image]

Please clarify my doubt